# Issues getting screenshots in emulator. parts of screen missing

Tags: linux, android-emulator, screenshots

Hello I am wondering if anyone has ever experienced this problem.

I am trying to take screenshots of my app (or any app that I have tried) in the emulator.  When I take a screenshot quite frequently part of the screen is corrupt / missing,  like shown below, it can happen anywhere on the screen not just on the keyboard. If when using `monitor` to take the screenshot I can refresh and it make work and take a proper picture or another area of the screen may then get the problem blank area.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Example screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

I am using android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.

My emulated device is Nexus 4, 4.4.2,  ARM cpu and any skin, no emulation options.

I have tried taking screenshots via `monitor` and `adb` but result in the same issue as seen in screenshot above.

Does anyone know how to fix this or am I going to have to take an ubuntu screenshot and crop to the android screen?

Answer (score 0):

> This may help:
>
> 1.Firstly start the emulator
>
> 2.Then go to the DDMS please select the emulator
>
> 3.Then left side we have button Screen Capture click this button
>
> 4.Screen Shot taken own App.
>
> [image]

Comment: The questioner knows how to take a screenshot. The issue is that it doesn't work correctly.